# TinyMCE / Prestashop - get HTML content

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

I'm currently working on a website and I have to use Prestashop.
I created a back office interface that allows the user to write, edit and delete articles. So I put a tinyMCE editor in it.

The problem is that when I click on 'save' to store the article in the database, it only stores raw text, without the styling content (html tags, bold text etc)

I would like to know how to get the whole content, including html tags, styling etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `self::TYPE_STRING` to `self::TYPE_HTML`

Comment: I think we should post this as an answer to the question, so other can find it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so all I had to do was to change self::TYPE_STRING to self::TYPE_HTML in my Article.php file.